# Convert to Image or use canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Just wondering if its better to convert a canvas drawing to an image before adding it to the DOM or is it better to just add the canvas itself?

I am using canvas to create the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your scenario.

Canvas may or may not allocate an extra memory buffer but typically shares the back buffer with the display buffer. This may not be the case if the pixel ratio is different from 1:1 (ie. retina displays).

Also, with canvas, if created using html tags, may be cleared by the browser under certain conditions such as window resize. This seem to be a lesser problem now though then it used to be (Chrome could also clear canvas when showing some dialogs).

Converting it to image gives an performance and memory overhead though: first to create the compressed image, then converting it to base-64 with additional 33% memory overhead, then pass it in as image source which triggers converting of the base-64 string into image file and then for decompressing it to bitmap.

Comment: I made a quick jsPerf in the meantime. Converting  a canvas to an image is significantly slower. 

http://jsperf.com/canvas-vs-converting-to-img

Just wondering if there are any benefits to having an img once everything is rendered.

Comment: @Sivapriyan an image is more "set in stone" and doesn't run the risk of loosing its content (or have its content altered for that matter) compared to a canvas element (some rare memory condition may change that but in general..). Besides from that, which all-in-all is a small risk for a canvas image as well, there is no real benefits that I can think of - the possible memory overhead would be more static with a canvas than the temporary overhead converting the canvas to an image though. The risks, overheads etc. must be weighted against the context it will be used for (UX being one factor) IMO

Answer (score 0):

sure convert it to image and add it as DOM object

if you resize canvas will clear itself ,then you will have empty area.